# NHibernate 1:n mapping to 1:1 with restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

I have my application liek this:

1. I have a class *Product*
2. I have user track this product, so class *Track*

Note multiple user can track one product, so the relationship between Product : Track is 1 : n

However, if user is currently signed in, it can only be *1* Track associated to Product, and in my list page, I should display a list of products with its track status for current user, something like:

- Product A  -  Tracked on 2011-01-01
- Product B  -  Not Tracked
- Product C  -  Tracked on 2010-12-20
- ...

Thus in plain sql, I may have a query like this:

```
select * from Product as p 
left outer join Track as t 
    on t.ProductId = p.Id and t.UserId = {currentUser.Id}
```

But using NHibernate I find it not easy to implement, currently I have a *ProductWithTrack* class, which inherits from *Product* class and adds a *Track* property:

```
class ProductWithTrack : Product {
    public Track Track { get; set; }
}
```

My effort is to map this class to Product table just the same as *Product* class, but *how can I figure the mapping of Track property*, I have tried:

- one-to-many, but Track is not a collection
- many-to-one / one-to-one, this requires a foreign key column in Product table which certainly not exists

Please help in this mapping problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is based on the observation that the list page is a reporting view of the data. In particular it combines information about products and their tracking status. For a reporting view, you don't need to create an explicit mapping for the desired data, instead you can use the [query capabilities](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries) of NHibernate and possibly [projections](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries#13%282E%297%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Projections%282C%29_aggregation_and_grouping) to get the results you need. In other words, ProductWithTrack does not need to be its own entity.

As another approach, instead of having ProductWithTrack inheriting from Product you should have a class called TrackedProduct:

```
class TrackedProduct {
 public int ID { get; private set; }
 public Product Product { get; private set; }
 public Track Track { get; private set; }
}
```

This class represents the concept of a tracked product and has its own identity. You can then query this entity to get the desired data.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused... I haved tried google "reporting view hibernate" but get no results, and if I have a class TrackedProduct with its own ID, then where does this ID come from ? Thanks very much.